# Supremum of the cardinalities of the minimum no. of generators among finite subgroups of $GL(n,F)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, infinite-groups, general-linear-group

For a finite group $G$, set $\mu(G):=\min\{|S|: G=\langle S\rangle\}$.

Given an infinite field $F$ and an integer $n\ge 1$, set

$$\mu_{n,F}:=\sup\{\mu(G): G \le GL(n,F), |G| \text{ is finite}\}.$$

$$\tau_{n,F}:=\sup\{\mu(G): G \le GL(n,F) \text{ is a finite abelian subgroup }\}.$$

Clearly, $\tau_{n,F}\le \mu_{n,F}$.

(1) Is it known when $\mu_{n,F}<\infty?$

(This is clearly true if $n=1$, since $GL(1,F)$ is just the multiplicative subgroup of $F$, and it is known that all it's finite subgroups are cyclic).

(2) Is it known when $\tau_{n,F}$ is finite?

Please help.

UPDATE: As shown by Eric Wofsey in the comments, $\tau_{n,F}$ is infinite whenever $F$ is an infinite field of finite positive characteristic and $n>1$.

The case of when $F$ has characteristic zero remains open.

Comment: If $F$ is the rationals (or a finite degree extension) this is true -- due to a theorem of Minkowski that bounds the orders of finite subgroups.

Comment: Well, if $n>1$ then the additive group of $F$ embeds in $GL(n,F)$ as unipotent matrices, so $\mu_{n,F}$ is infinite if $F$ has finite characteristic.  The characteristic $0$ case seems harder though.

Comment: @ahulpke: Thanks, could you please provide a reference to the theorem of Minkowski you're referring to? I also added one more question where I vary over only finite abelian subgroups ...

Comment: @strat. H. Minkowski, Zur Theorie der positiven quadratischen Formen, J.Crelle 101 (1887), 196–202 (= Ges.Abh., Band I, n◦VI).   (Cited from https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL3821667391778701726_6___Bounds_for_the_orders.pdf. , not checked myself)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: I get that $F$ embeds inside $GL(n,F)$, but why does that guarantee finite subgroups of arbitrarily high degree when $F$ has finite characteristic? I get that $F$ would be an infinite extension of $\mathbb F_p$, but will intermediate field extensions of arbitrarily high degree occur?

Comment: @strat: You don't need intermediate field extensions, you can just take $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector subspaces of $F$, which have arbitrarily high dimension since $F$ is infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 4):

Since we can extend scalars, to show finiteness of $\mu_{n,F}$ in characteristic zero $F$, it suffices to check for $F=\mathbb{C}$, since any finite subgroup only needs finitely many coefficients of the matrices, and we can pick an embedding into $\mathbb{C}$.

So now we quote the following result, due to Jordan (Theorem 14.2 in Isaac's Character Theory of finite groups), that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that any finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ has an abelian normal subgroup $A$ of index less than $f(n)$. So knowing this, given any finite subgroup $G$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, we have this normal abelian subgroup, and we can restrict our map to get an $n$ dimensional faithful representation of $A$, so we see that $A$ requires at most $n$ generators, since our representation splits into a sum of one dimensional representations, each with cyclic image.

So then since $A$ has index less than $f(n)$, we can pick lifts of each element in $G/A$, and together these generate $G$, so we have generated $G$ with at most $n+f(n)$ elements, so $\mu_{n,F}$ is finite for $F$ of characteristic zero.

One can also read about the theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Schur_theorem, which gives some explicit upper bounds for $f(n)$.